# StereoCalibration in OpenCV: Shouldn't this work without ObjectPoints?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I have two questions relating to stereo calibration with opencv. I have many pairs of calibration images like these:

[image: right]

[image: left]

Across the set of calibration images the distance of the chessboard away from the camera varies, and it is also rotated in some shots.

From within this scene I would like to map pairs of image coordinates (x,y) and (x',y') onto object coordinates in a global frame: (X,Y,Z).

In order to calibrate the system I have detected pairs of image coordinates of all chessboard corners using cv2.DetectChessboardCorners(). From reading Hartley's Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision I gather I should be able to calibrate this system up to a scale factor without actually specifying the object points of the chessboard corners. First question: Is this correct?

Investigating cv2's capabilities, the closest thing I've found is cv2.stereoCalibrate(objectpoints,imagepoints1,imagepoints2).

I have obtained imagepoints1 and imagepoints2 from cv2.findChessboardCorners. Apparently from the images shown I can approximately extract (X,Y,Z) relative to the frame on the calibration board (by design), which would allow me to apply cv2.stereoCalibrate(). However, I think this will introduce error, and it prevents me from using all of the rotated photos of the calibration board which I have. Second question: Can I calibrate without object points using opencv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You must specify the object points. Note that they need not change across the image sequence, since you can interpret the change as due to camera motion relative to the target. Also, you can (should) assume that Z=0 for a planar target like yours. You may specify X,Y up to scale, and thus obtain after calibration translations up to scale.
2. No

**Clarification**: by "need not change across the image sequence" I mean that you can assume the target fixed in the world frame, and interpret the relative motion as due to the camera only. The world frame itself, absent a better prior, can be defined by the pose of the target in any one of the images (say, the first one). Obviously, I do not mean that the pose of the target relative to the camera does not change - in fact, it must change in order to obtain a calibration. If you do have a better prior, you should use if. For example, if the target moves on a turntable, you should solve directly for the parameters of the cylindrical motion, since there is less of them (one constant axis, one constant radius, plus one angle per image, rather than 6 parameters per image).

Comment: "Note that they need not change across the image sequence, since you can interpret the change as due to camera motion relative to the target."

Please note this is stereocalibration, not camera calibration. Are you sure this remains true?

Comment: Of course, you can only solve for relative motion. Clarified meaning in answer.